# .htaccess Disable mod_security for specific IPs

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-security

On my server there is enabled mod_security and I want to disable it with .htaccess for 3 specific IP address. Is that possible?

I tried something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
   SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^1.2.3.4$" "phase:1,t:none,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off,ctl:auditEngine=Off,id:9999"
</IfModule>
```

but seams like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rule looks good to me.

ModSecurity 2.7 requires the following flag to be added at compile time to allow .htaccess to alter settings so I presume you've included that (it's not set by default)?:

```
--enable-htaccess-config
```

To test if this is the problem you could move your rule to the main Apache config and see if it works there.

I would also suggest adding logging, to see if the rule is fired and/or adding debug logging to see if it reaches there or gives a clue as to why not.

Comment: I didn't compile, I installed it from repository `apt-get install libapache2-modsecurity` . So it cannot be enabled after installation?

Comment: Don't think so. It's a security feature. But check first that that's definitely the issue.